# while using decodeURIComponent(atob(str)) its returning back with error saying Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBtb25vc3BhY2U7IGZvbnQtc2l6ZTogbWVkaXVtOyBiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiByZ2IoMjM5LCAyMzksIDIzOSk7Ij4mcXVvdDt+IUAjJCVeJmFtcDsqKClfK3t9fDomcXVvdDsmbHQ7Jmd0Oz9+IUAjJCVeJmFtcDsqKCZxdW90Ozwvc3Bhbj48cD48L3A+";

unescape(atob(str));// able to decodeURIComponent;
```

but with `decodeURIComponent(atob(str));` I'm getting exception saying `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`.

After `atob(str)`, the response is coming with 2 '%', if i remove the % then the `decodeURIComponent` is working fine. Why with % its not coming , and what is the substitute for that, and i don't want to use `unescape`, as it's deprecate?

any solution for this ?

Comment: if i do atob(str), where the str is defined above , so atob("PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBtb25vc3BhY2U7IGZvbnQtc2l6ZTogbWVkaXVtOyBiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiByZ2IoMjM5LCAyMzksIDIzOSk7Ij4mcXVvdDt+IUAjJCVeJmFtcDsqKClfK3t9fDomcXVvdDsmbHQ7Jmd0Oz9+IUAjJCVeJmFtcDsqKCZxdW90Ozwvc3Bhbj48cD48L3A+")   =  "<span style="font-family: monospace; font-size: medium; background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);">&quot;~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?~!@#$^&amp;*(&quot;</span><p></p>"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by calling decodeURIComponent after base64 decoding the string?

Comment: Converting to UTF-8 format, if there is a URL then atob is not enough to handle this , so we we can pass the the atob(str) inside decodeURIComponent. earlier the same was achieved by using unescape but now its deprecated .instead we are using  decodeURIComponent, does it make sense?

Comment: I see, that does make sense. Do you have an example that includes unicode characters that you would be able to share? decodeURIComponent is certainly the wrong function to be using here, but since I'm not sure exactly how the unicode characters are encoded I'm not sure what you should be using instead.